# Add MS Bot Framework Chatbot to all MS Teams Channels

Tags: azure, botframework, microsoft-teams

I am having a BotFramework Chatbot, deployed on Azure. I want it to be by default available for all the MS Teams Channels/Teams as I deployed/added it into the MS Teams.

Comment: So what is the issue you are having with? Could you please clarify that.

Comment: I am new into it. Please suggest the steps or approach to implement it.

Comment: Once you have added the `teams channel` on azure portal then [follow this guidelines here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/channel-connect-teams?view=azure-bot-service-4.0). If you have any further confusion feel free to share your problem exactly what issue you are facing there.

Comment: It's not possible to add bot to all teams channels using configurations. Either you need to install manually to each team or you can automate using Graph API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-post-installedapps?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Answer (score 0):

To make your custom bot framework available in teams, you need to make it as a package.

Steps to be followed:

1. You need to create a bot using Azure bot framework
2. Plan your app with teams features (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/app-fundamentals-overview)
3. Get the embedded code.
4. To publish and distribute your bot in Microsoft teams, follow(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/deploy-and-publish/apps-publish-overview)

Other reference links:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/channel-connect-teams?view=azure-bot-service-4.0

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/app-fundamentals-overview